# Dropbox is showing folders, and then isn't

Tags: dropbox

When I first enter one shared Dropbox directory, it first shows me all of the sub-directories as well. After a brief moment, though, it stops showing them. They disappear completely from my browsing options, and appear **only** when I search them through the search bar, on the top right.

I didn't find anything that'd help me with that, and it persists on both the Edge and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Problem solved by the support team, without giving any explanation as for what has happened...

Comment: Maybe you can mark this as  solved?

Comment: @RayB sure, how?

Comment: You can post what you found as an answer and mark accepted

Comment: I've never found out, though. A week passed and it got solved. Maybe it's best to just delete it? @RayB